# How to read data from USB com port using nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is my nodejs code to get weighing data that connected through USB com port but its not working can anyone help .

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
var path = require('path');
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline')

app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

const serialPort = new SerialPort({
    path: 'COM1',
    baudRate: 9600,
})
const parser = serialPort.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))

app.get('/getweighdata', function (req, res) {
    parser.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("data-------" + data)
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any errors ?

Comment: when i run this code on the browser, there is no  error but not getting any output.